# How to query vsts artifacts with tags

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

we would like to query artefacts with tags to trigger parallel deployments. How should we do that? Is there an UI or do we have to use the API ?

Comment: What's the detail workflow of your requirement? How about continue deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no UI for this, you're going to be looking at [the VSTS Build Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-build-artifacts) to build this.

Comment: checked this one https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/xamlbuild/builds . where is it ?

Comment: There is no direct query API, so you'll first have to grab builds by tags, then fetch the details and fetch the artefacts by build.

Comment: this one https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds then use tagfilters.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to these steps below:

1. Add a PowerShell or other (e.g. Command) task to call [Logging Commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) to add build tag (e.g. `Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]tagTest"`)
2. [Specify conditions for that PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/conditions)
3. Open release definition
4. Specify the Artifact filters with build tags (You also can specify the filter for Continuous deployment)

[image]

5. After that, the environments that meet the filters will be running